# Django: Updating only changed values in a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model with 10 fields. Through a modelform I show only 8 of them on the template for the user to edit.

The problem is that when I save the form data It changes all non shown fields to empty. It seems like you HAVE to show ALL the fields in the template.

I´m trying to get the list of `changed_data` and then use the `update_fields` with it, it doesn´t work.

How can I achieve this? What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**The view**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    perfil_cliente_form = EmpresaForm(request.POST, instance=contactos)
    if perfil_cliente_form.is_valid():
        cliente = perfil_cliente_form.save(commit=False)
        campos_editados = perfil_cliente_form.changed_data
        cliente.FechaModi = date.today()
        cliente.save(update_fields=campos_editados)
```

**The form**

```
class EmpresaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contactos
        fields = ("Vendedor", "codigo", 'Nombre', 'Razonsociallegal',
                  "NombrePcia", "Localidad", "Domicilio", "CodPostal", "CodigoZona",
                  "Telefonos", "emailEmpresa", "Fax",
                  "Descuento1", "NroDoc", "SituacionIVA", "BancoCBU", "SituacionEmpleador", "SituacionGanancias",
                  "Comentario1", "Comentario2", "Concepto1",
                  "Agrupacion1", "Agrupacion2", "EsCliente", "EsVendedor",
                  "FechaAlta", "FechaModi", "FechaUltOp", "FechaUltVenta",
                  "IIBBCMJurisSede", "IIBBNroEsCUIT", "IIBBSituacion", "Lista",
                  "MTCategoria", "PorcLiberacion", "ProFAREBasePend", "PuntosDeVenta",
                  "PR", "TD", "CpCliente")
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `changed_data`? Confirm that it doesn't contain the fields that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Show your form class

Comment: @farooq Yes I checked and the `changed_data` shows the correct data.

Comment: @dan-klasson Just updated the post with the form class

Comment: I see lots of fields in your form class. Does all of those get shown to the user?

Comment: I would just create a new form which specifies only those 8 fields. Then use that in your view

Comment: @dan-klasson I tried that and works. But is still strange that the `update_fields` is not working as it should. Thanks anyway. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can vote you up?

Comment: @FranciscoGhelfi Ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the fields on your model are set to `blank=True` they will just get updated with blank values if your custom form do not have those fields present.

I would just create a new form which specifies only those 8 fields. Then use that in your view.